# how to save a list of data to a variable in flutter dart

Tags: list, flutter, variables, dart, save

```
var users = [
{id :3,name : adel,description: agent},{ id :4,name : anu,description: Manager,},
{id:5,name:arun,description:poen}
]
```

here i want to save each json object save in separate variable ,so i can acess it easily, how to do that

```
for (int i =0; i<users.length;i++)
{
 var descrip = users[i]['description'];
}
```

when i using this above loop method ,the variable saves only the last data in the list , im new to flutter , anyone know how to save this data to variable ,please help me

Comment: Do you mean, you want saparate list of all descriptions?

Comment: The reason you're getting only the last data is because the `var descrip` is a single value and not of type array in which you're suppose to save the values in if you want to save all the description in it. You will need to define `var descrip = new List(users.length)` and add the value with `descrip.add(users[i]['description'])`

Comment: @sajith lakmal yes separate list of description and it save this to variable descrip

Comment: @BelleZaid i checked this one ,but it shows the error  " Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to a fixed-length list "

Comment: Actually `new List()` is deprecated. You should rather use [] or `List.filled(length, fill)`

Comment: Thanks @quoci I didn't know it was deprecated. Left flutter only for a bit and it's deprecated. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> usersJson = [
{'id': 3, 'name': 'adel', 'description': 'agent'},
{ 'id': 4, 'name': 'anu', 'description': 'Manager',},
{'id': 5, 'name': 'arun', 'description': 'poen'}

 ];
   

 List<String> descriptions = [];

for (int i =0; i<users.length;i++)
{
 descriptions.add(users[i]['description']);
}
```

Comment: I think you know what was the problem as Belle Zaid said.

Answer (score 0):

As Belle Zaid said you declared your variable **descrip** inside your loop and overwrite it on each step. That's the reason why you only get your last value. First you need to declare a List outside of the for loop and inside the loop you add each value to the list.

```
final List<String> descrip = [];
for(int i = 0;i < users.length; i++){
  descrip.add(users[i]['description']);
}
```